# NodeJS "class.function is not a function"

Tags: node.js, typescript

logic.ts

```
import * as ModelA from "./ModelA";
import * as ModelB from "./ModelB";


export function ProcessPurchases(purchases: ModelA.Purchase[], useInfo: boolean = false): ModelA.Purchase[] {
    ...
    return purchases;

};

export function findSavings(Products: ModelA.Purchase[], OtherProducts: ModelA.Purchase[]): ModelA.Savings{
      ....
      return savings;
};
```

server.ts

```
import * as ModelA from "./ModelA";
import * as ModelB from "./ModelB";
import * as Algorithms from "./logic";


import * as _ from "lodash";


var tp = require('tedious-promises');
var dbConfig = {
    ...
};

var TYPES = require('tedious').TYPES;
tp.setConnectionConfig(dbConfig); // global scope
tp.setPromiseLibrary('es6');

const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var request = require('request');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.listen(3000, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    throw err
  }
  console.log('Server started on port 3000')
})


interface IKeyValue { [key: string]: any };

namespace ProcessLogic{

    function PurchaseSHR(Group: number[], Manufacturer: number, Category: number, useInfo= false): ModelA.Savings{
    ...
    if (useInfo) {
        var result= Algorithms.ProcessPurchases(myActualPurchases); //Algorithms.ProcessPurchases is not a function
        ...
        return result;
    }
    else {
        ...
      }
  }


}
```

}

throws error that Algorithms.ProcessPurchases is not a function, no build errors only at runtime. All files are under same directory.
**Things i have tried :**

wrap the logic functions under namespace "Algorithms" and import them like so:

```
import {Algorithms} from "./logic"
```

also tried to reference via: `/// <reference path="logic.ts" />`

Comment: Have you already tried `export function functionA(){...}`?

Comment: Please provide an MCVE.

Comment: @SayanPal yes i have, that is how i currently have it. Edited my post to reflect

Comment: Please add some code for example for `functionA` so that the problem can reproduced, refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. By the way, as per your posted code, `functionA` is still lacking function syntax, missing parentheses; with that in place it should work.

Comment: @SayanPal i have updated the post to reflect my actual code more accurately based on the mcve, please let me know if additional info is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by creating new .ts file, and rewriting all the code in it. Weirdly everything seems to be working fine now..